# How to bootstrap/setup Angular2 in an existing Laravel project?

Tags: php, angular, single-page-application

I am looking to implement Angular2 inside my current Laravel project. I've read about many setups including AngularClass's version with Webpack, but I feel like it's all over-complicated.

### What I wish to make:

- A simple single page app **inside** my Laravel app.
- It needs to have something like Grunt/Gulp or even Webpack to **compile upon changes**.
- Does not need NodeJs to run in **production**, no lite-server, just like AngularJS it can be injected and that's it.
- I need to understand the implementation files to achieve this, so no starterpack or angular-cli, unless if you can supply good arguments.

Looking for a "how to"-like example on creating the above.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: More information

As ANKH pointed out, i needed a more detailed and coursed question. So here we go:
- Looking for a example implementation of a Angular2 based SPA inside an existing PHP application (Laravel). 
- I've tried many different tutorials, going from the heroes tour, to Sitepoint and AngularCLI based tutorials, but they all assume a SPA on it's own. Ergo, they are compiled and served through NodeJS, which I don't need.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I've tried explaining my goal a bit more, maybe this helps.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out that I've actually been looking at this entirely wrong. I've gone with using Angular-cli and found that I could generate the output files and include these inside my Laravel project. No need to integrate them further.